# Flutter archive build fails due to pod linking error

Tags: xcode, flutter

I am trying to build a Flutter app that uses Firestore, Cloud Functions, and Auth to upload to the App Store. I can use Flutter to build for iOS without problems, but building in XCode for a generic device fails. The build fails in the link stage with the error after a whole bunch of warnings about not finding the directories of various pods:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/jpsheehan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbsrfhxjslbqvrhhrsdoiilfifvz/Build/Products/Release-production-iphoneos/AppAuth'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/jpsheehan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbsrfhxjslbqvrhhrsdoiilfifvz/Build/Products/Release-production-iphoneos/BoringSSL-GRPC'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/jpsheehan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dbsrfhxjslbqvrhhrsdoiilfifvz/Build/Products/Release-production-iphoneos/FirebaseAuth'
...

ld: library not found for -lAppAuth
```

I have tried the following things without success:

- Open `Runner.xcworkspace`, not `Runner.xcproject`
- Delete `Podfile`, `Podfile.lock`, and `Pods\`
- Drag `Pods.xcworkspace` into `Pods` folder in XCode

Does anyone have recommendations for how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my config files were not including the proper Pods-Runner files after I added flavors to flutter. I modified them to point to the correct paths.

**Broken Version**

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig"
#include "Generated.xcconfig"
```

**Working Version**

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug-production.xcconfig"
#include "Generated.xcconfig"
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours trying to fix this bug. Ultimately this is how I was able to resolve it

1. Before starting with Xcode Archive, used flutter build iOS
2. Changed the IOS Deployment Target to a higher target iOS 11.2 . Earlier I had something like 8.0 which was giving all the above errors.
3. Made sure that the IOS deployment targets in Xcode are same in the Project, Target and Pods